# Limiting concurrency spawning and waiting for worker processes

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I've got a C# program which queues up a set of work items. For each work item, I spawn another application (which I can't change) to process that item. This process is relatively CPU-intensive. I'd like to limit the number of instances of this application.

I've considered using PLINQ:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    workItems,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
    x => Process.Start("worker", x).WaitForExit());
```

But my concern is that each parallel worker will use up a thread merely to wait for the corresponding process.

I've also seen that PLINQ attempts to batch the items returned, which means that it might stall while waiting for an appropriately-sized batch. So, maybe a single-producer/multiple-consumer pattern using `BlockingCollection` would work? The problem with that is that I'd have one thread per each parallel worker, which would (?) be worse than the PLINQ solution.

Given that the above is simplified and that I actually have a `TaskCompletionSource` connected to each worker process (via the `Exited` event), could I use something from the TPL to do this without blocking any background threads?

Comment: How bad was the profiling that individual threads in TPL were a problem?

Comment: Sorry: academic exercise. Actually blocking with 4 (or 8) threads isn't actually a problem, but I'd like to know more about scheduling and concurrency options in TPL.

Comment: Yes, I can use C# 5.0 and .NET 4.5 are available.

Answer (score 1):

If you can wrap the `Process` start and finish using the `Process.Exited` event in a `Task`:

```
Task WrapExternalProcess( WorkItem workItem ) { ... }
```

You can use continuations to remove blocking altogether. Something like this would do:

```
Task DoAllWork( IEnumerable<WorkItem> workItems )
{
  int THREAD_COUNT = 4;

  var bag = new ConcurrentBag<WorkItem>( workItems );
  var ce = new CountdownEvent( THREAD_COUNT );
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < THREAD_COUNT ; i++ ) Work( bag, ce, tcs );

  return tcs.Task;
}

void Work(
  ConcurrentBag<WorkItem> bag,
  CountdownEvent ce,
  TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs
)
{
    WorkItem workItem;
    if ( bag.TryTake( out workItem) )
    {
        WrapExternalProcess( workItem )
          .ContinueWith( t => Work( bag, ce, tcs ) );
    }
    else // no more work
    {
        // If I'm the last thread to finish
        if ( ce.Signal() ) tcs.SetResult( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Blocking on `WaitForExit` isn't needed: I subscribe to the `Process.Exited` event.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something like the following:

```
var sem = new SemaphoreSlim(4);
foreach (var item in workItems)
{
    sem.Wait();

    ProcessAsync(item).ContinueWith(_ => sem.Release());
}
```

This gives me a single thread that keeps a limited number of background processes in flight at once.

Comment: But why do you need to block that one thread? Couldn't you do the same thing without blocking any threads?

Comment: Dunno. Can I? This is the closest I've got to not using any threads. I had to add some other stuff to keep track of how many items were outstanding (since it leaves the loop with N<=3 items remaining), but this does work.